# Class Change on selecting dropdown and checkbox both together

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<form id="xyz" class="checkbox-form">
    <input class="chk" type="checkbox" id="a" value="">
    <label for="a" class="checkbox-inline">Apple</label>

    <input class="chk" type="checkbox" id="b" value="">
    <label for="b" class="checkbox-inline">Banana</label>

    <input class="chk" type="checkbox" id="c" value="" >
    <label for="c" class="checkbox-inline">Carrot</label>

    <select name="Select Shop" id="shoplist">
        <option value="s01">shop1<option>
        <option value="s02">shop2<option>
        <option value="s03">shop3<option>
    </select>

    <select name="Select City" id="citylist">
        <option value="c01">city1<option>
        <option value="c02">city2<option>
        <option value="c03">city3<option>
    </select> 
</form>
<div class="a b city1 shop2">xyz...<div>
<div class="c b city2 shop1">xyz...<div>
<div class="a c city3 shop1">xyz...<div>
<div class="b a city2 shop2">xyz...<div>
```

Now i want to show only those divs which have the above class selected in the form. 
eg.  i want to show divs with class a,c checked and city3 and shop1 selected from the dropdown . then it hide all divs and just show the thirdone

Comment: Please show your JavaScript code.

Answer (score 0):

In this you should give display none to all the classes for the div except the main class for styling and static classes. So change your div to

```
<div class="a b city1 shop2 a-static b-static city1-static shop2-static mainStyleClass">xyz...<div>
```

Here `a`, `b`, `city1` and `shop2` should have display none, and once these classes are removed by the code below, the div will start showing.

An example method for the checkbox. Dropdown should be easy on similar lines.

```
$('.checkbox-inline').change(function() {
    if(this.checked) {
        $('div.' + $(this).text()).removeClass($(this).text());
    }
    else {
        $('div.' + $(this).text() + '-static').addClass($(this).text());
    }
});
```

Comment: this i know . i have a module that require checkbox and select dropdown both . i have to show the elements that have this combination

Answer (score 0):

First you need to close the div tags properly.

Then, can get the desired result in following logic :

1. Get the list of classes as per checkbox and select input selection.
2. Hide All divs
3. Show the div which has all these selected classes and number of classes are same as the selected one.

Check the below code. Hope this helps!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("div").hide();
  var elems = $('.chk,#citylist,#shoplist');
  elems.on('change', function() {
    var arr = [];
    $.each(elems, function(i, e) {
      var elem = $(e);
      var val;
      if (elem.is("select")) {
        val = elem.find("option:selected").text();
      } else if (elem.is("input[type='checkbox']")) {
        val = elem.is(":checked") ? elem.attr("id") : "";
      }

      if (val) {
        arr.push(val);
      }

    });

    $.each($("div"), function(i, e) {
      var hasCl = true;
      $.each(arr, function(k, c) { 
        if (!$(e).hasClass(c)) {
          hasCl = false;
        }
      });
      if (hasCl) {
        $(e).show();
      } else {
        $(e).hide();
      }
    });

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<form id="xyz" class="checkbox-form">
  <input class="chk" type="checkbox" id="a" value="">
  <label for="a" class="checkbox-inline">Apple</label>

  <input class="chk" type="checkbox" id="b" value="">
  <label for="b" class="checkbox-inline">Banana</label>

  <input class="chk" type="checkbox" id="c" value="">
  <label for="c" class="checkbox-inline">Carrot</label>

  <select name="Select Shop" id="shoplist">
        <option value="s01">shop1<option>
        <option value="s02">shop2<option>
        <option value="s03">shop3<option>
    </select>

  <select name="Select City" id="citylist">
        <option value="c01">city1<option>
        <option value="c02">city2<option>
        <option value="c03">city3<option>
    </select>
</form>

<div class="a b city1 shop2">xyz...1</div>
<div class="c b city2 shop1">xyz...2</div>
<div class="a c city3 shop1">xyz...3</div>
<div class="b a city2 shop2">xyz...4</div>
```

P.S. : It is expected to add the code you tried in the question!

Comment: sorry i wasn't aware that we have to add links here . 
thing is i want to show all those divs which have selected and checked class . 
eg if have checked a then all divs with class a showed up, if i am selecing shop 1 and checked c, then all divs that have 1 & c in it shoud showup

Comment: check updated answer! It will show the div if all selected classes are their to that div. (If you want to show it as OR condition then you need change a logic bit which I feel you can attempt!)